# How to prove $\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{n+1} = \prod \limits_{i = 2}^n \frac{2i-1}{i+1} $?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

How to prove this closed form involving [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)? $$\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{n+1} = \prod \limits_{i = 2}^n \frac{2 \times (2i-1)}{i+1} $$

I have seen this being used [here](http://n00tc0d3r.blogspot.in/2013/07/unique-binary-search-trees.html). Not sure how to derive it. Any ideas?

Comment: The formula is false; the right hand side isn't even an integer for $n=3$.

Comment: There may be a typo because it does not hold when $n=2$. (By the way, $n\ge 2$, right?)

Comment: I think I have solved this one myself.

Comment: It is hard to argue with someone named Quixotic but it is courtesy and good gesture to accept an answer when someone has taken the trouble to answer a question. Just my 2-bits worth.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that $\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$. But 
$$(2n)!=\left(1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots \cdot(2n-1)\right)\left(2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots\cdot(2n)\right)$$
(we separated the odd numbers and the even numbers).

The product of the even numbers $2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots(2n)$ is $2^n n!$.
From this it follows that
$$\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{2^n}{(n+1)!}\left(1\cdot 3\cdot5 \cdots \cdot(2n-1)\right).$$
That is equal to the expression of the OP. For it can be written as 
$$\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{2\cdot(2i-1)}{i+1}.$$
Starting at $i=2$, as the revised OP does, eliminates one factor of $2$ from both the numerator and the denominator, so makes no difference.